# C# equivalent of method in unmanaged code

Tags: c#, com

I need to call a method in a dll

```
DWORD PLIC_API RFPerso_GetMifare1KData(BYTE*  pbUid,
                                       DWORD  dwUidLength,
                   RFPERSO_GEN_MIF_STD_DATA*  pRFMifData, //Its a structure
                                      DWORD*  pdwLicCount);
```

What would be its equivalent in C#. I am using the below method at c# side, however I am getting a parameter mismatched error.

```
[DllImport("NercoPic.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern uint RFPerso_GetMifare1KData(  byte[] pbUid,
                                                   uint dwUidLength,
                              ref RFPERSO_GEN_MIF_STD_DATA pRFMifData,
                                                 ref  uint pdwLicCount);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT** : **Calling Code**

```
string uid = "DEDE";

byte[] uidArray= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(uid);
 AA.RFPERSO_GEN_MIF_STD_DATA data = new AA.RFPERSO_GEN_MIF_STD_DATA (
                      0, 0, new AA.RFPERSO_GEN_MIF_BLOCK[4]
                      {
                          new AA.RFPERSO_GEN_MIF_BLOCK(default(byte),default(byte),default(byte),new byte[16]),
                          new AA.RFPERSO_GEN_MIF_BLOCK(default(byte),default(byte),default(byte),new byte[16]),
                          new AA.RFPERSO_GEN_MIF_BLOCK(default(byte),default(byte),default(byte),new byte[16]),
                          new AA.RFPERSO_GEN_MIF_BLOCK(default(byte),default(byte),default(byte),new byte[16]) }
                     )  ;

uint licCount=0;
i = AA.RFPerso_GetMifare1KData( uidArray, 4, ref data,ref licCount);
```

Comment: Why you passed `byte[]` as `byte*`?

Comment: Whats the specific error?

Comment: its a 4 byte UID and in some other dll I passed byte* as byte[] and it worked.

Comment: Did you use the DllImportAttribute as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern

Comment: should I used ref or out for a pointer equivalent

Comment: Please add some complete c and c# code (structure, attributes, how you call this, how does the C++ behave, etc.). This is not enough to help

Comment: @ManuelFuchs yes, I am using dllimport

Comment: @SimonMourier please see my edit

Comment: `//Its a structure`.  It is not, you pass an array of structures.  Might well be correct.  An array is already a reference type, don't use `ref`.  You need [In, Out] since the structure doesn't look blittable.  Not actually that likely that this caused the failure, unmanaged code typically fails with an AccessViolationException when you get the pointer wrong.  My money is on the *licCount* variable, set it to the number of elements in the array so it knows how many it contains.  You might need more than 4, ymmv.

Comment: @HansPassant You mean to say that I should pass array of structure RFPERSO_GEN_MIF_STD_DATA. And instead of ref, I should use out?

Comment: Neither ref nor out, an array already is marshalled as a pointer.